# How to prevent resending data after it sent once in Express

Tags: javascript, express, mailgun

I have this route that sends an email after a user fill out the contact form.

```
var express = require('express');
var mailRouter = express.Router();
var Mailgun = require('mailgun-js');

var api_key = 'key-xxxxxxxxxxxx';
var domain = 'xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.mailgun.org';

var router = function(){
  mailRouter.route('/send')
    .post(function(req, res){
      console.log(req.body);
      var body = req.body;

      var mailgun = new Mailgun({apiKey: api_key, domain: domain});

      var mailOptions = {
        from: body.email,
        to: 'wewe99@yopmail.com',
        subject: 'Oxedio Inquiry',
        text: 'Hi, I am ' + body.name + '. ' + body.message + '. You can contact me @ ' + body.phone
      };

      mailgun.messages().send(mailOptions, function(err, body){
        if(err){
          res.render('error', {error: err});
          console.log(err);
        } else{
          res.render('success', {mail: body});
          console.log(body);
        };
      });
    });

  return mailRouter;
};


module.exports = router;
```

The problem here is that when the user click the submit button, it will go to this route, sends the email / message then when the user refreshes on this landing page, the email / message will be resent. Can anyone give a tip on how to fix this? I have tried using req.session.destoy() but I don't think i have a session so it doesn't work. I also tried to setTimeout then redirect to homepage after some time the success message is displayed but I think that was not a good idea because the user can still refresh the page in that point of time. What I want is that when the user refresh the page, the email will only be sent once.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common fix for this is to redirect the user to a different URL once the action has been completed. That way, if they reload the page, they reload the new page instead of submitting the form data again.

For example:

```
mailgun.messages().send(mailOptions, function(err, body){
  if (err){
    req.session.mailError = err;
  } else{
    req.session.mailError = false;
    req.session.mailBody  = body;
  };
  res.redirect('/thankyou');
});
```

And you declare a new route for `/thankyou`:

```
mailRouter.get('/thankyou', function(req, res) {
  if (req.session.mailError) {
    res.render('error', { error: req.session.mailError });
  } else {
    res.render('success', { mail: req.session.mailBody });
  }
});
```

This requires that you use sessions, for instance using [`express-session`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). If you don't, you either have to start using them, or find another way to propagate the error/body to the "thank you" page (although besides sessions there aren't a lot of other alternatives).

If you don't really need to pass the specific error, or the body, you can make two separate routes that would render either a generic error, or a generic "thank you" message, and redirect to the appropriate one:

```
  if (err) {
    res.redirect('/mail-error');
  } else {
    res.redirect('/thankyou');
  }
```

Then those pages would just show a generic message.

Comment: It said Cannot set property 'mailError' of undefined.

Comment: @MixAustria oh right, sorry, I mistakenly assumed that you would be using [sessions](https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-session). I'll edit my answer to provide some more information.